# Question:Suppose that {sn} and {tn} are a sequence of positive numbers, that lim→∞sn/tn=∞ and that tn→∞.what can you conclude ?

Tags: real-analysis

Question:Suppose that $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ are a sequence of  positive numbers, that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} s_n/t_n=∞$ and that $(t_n)→∞$.what can you conclude ?

$\lim_{n→∞} \ s_n/t_n=∞$ then to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(s_n)$ =  ∞ also? can someone show me how I can proof this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

- What's the limit of $\frac{|s_n|}{|t_n|}$?
- Deduce that $|s_n|\ge|t_n|$ for $n$ large enough and conclude.

Answer (score 2):

You have $\dfrac{s_n}{t_n} > k$ for some large $n > N \implies s_n > kt_n$. The answer follows.

Comment: You need some $\exists$'s and $\forall$'s in there to turn this into mathematics.

Comment: That makes mathematics difficult to read.  What's wrong with "there exists" and "for all"?  Let's make math easier to understand, not harder.

Comment: n$∀$h th$\mathfrak{o}$, $\mathbb{I}$t n$∃$Eds m$\mathcal{O}$r$e$ $\mathbb{S}$y$\mathfrak{M}$bols

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Show that if $s_{n}$ is bounded, and $t_{n} \to \infty$, then $s_{n}/t_{n}$ is bounded.